# Why the values of the coefficients of interaction terms by using : and * in glm() will be different in r?

Tags: r, glm

I tried to fit a Poisson regression with a continuous and factor variable.

The sample data is as below:

```
dependent = c(1:10)
x1 = c(12:22)
x2 = as.factor(sample(c(0,1), 10, replace = TRUE))
```

The code I used:

```
glm(dependent~x1*x2,family = 'poisson')

glm(dependent~x1:x2,family = 'poisson')
```

The result:

```
> glm(dependent~x1*x2,family = 'poisson')

Call:  glm(formula = dependent ~ x1 * x2, family = "poisson")

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x1          x21       x1:x21  
   -1.93517      0.21209      0.48128     -0.03257  

Degrees of Freedom: 9 Total (i.e. Null);  6 Residual
Null Deviance:      16.64 
Residual Deviance: 0.9667   AIC: 42.93
> 
> glm(dependent~x1:x2,family = 'poisson')

Call:  glm(formula = dependent ~ x1:x2, family = "poisson")

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       x1:x20       x1:x21  
    -1.7127       0.1998       0.1930  

Degrees of Freedom: 9 Total (i.e. Null);  7 Residual
Null Deviance:      16.64 
Residual Deviance: 1.028    AIC: 40.99
```

In the latter formula - `glm(formula = dependent ~ x1:x2, family = "poisson")`,

`x1:x20` was also included in the result.

However,
in `glm(formula = dependent ~ x1 * x2, family = "poisson")`,

there was only `x1:x21` in the result.

Is there anything I made mistakes? Please give me some suggestions, thank you!

Comment: `x1:x2` defines only the interactions between `x1` and `x2`.  `x1*x2` specifies the _crossing_ of `x1` with `x2`, which includes their main effects.  You don't see both interaction coefficients when you use `x1*x2` because your model also includes an intercept and is therfore overparameterised.  Read the Details section of the online doc for more information.

Comment: But why in the case of x1:x2, the coefficient of intercept still appeared...?

Comment: The intercept is included by default.  You have to explicitly remove it with `... - 1`.  I don't have a reference to hand to confirm that statement.

Comment: Now I understand...In the model 1, x1:x20 disappeared because of collinearity with x1. However, in the model 2, there was no more collinearity problem, so x1:x20 appeared.